# What other video format WPF MediaElement supports other than wmv and avi

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know which video formats my WPF application can play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162387/how-to-know-which-video-formats-my-wpf-application-can-play)

I know WPF MediaElement supports wmv and avi video formats, i am curious to know what are other video formats which WPF MediaElement supports.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which video formats my WPF application can play?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4162387/1136211).

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158650/wpf-media-formats